# boost::asio с boost::coroutine: ассинхронное ожидание своей операции

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Нашел пример ассинхронного tcp сервера на boost::asio. Каким образом можно приостановить выполнение сопрограммы и ассинхронно подождать возобновления по выполнению операции в другом потоке?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using std::begin;
using std::end;

int main()
{
    asio::io_service iosvc;
    tcp::socket s(iosvc);
    tcp::resolver r(iosvc);

    tcp::acceptor a(iosvc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 6767));

    a.accept(s);
    {
        asio::spawn(iosvc, [&iosvc,&s](asio::yield_context yield)
        {
            char data[256];
            while (s.is_open())
            {
                size_t n = s.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), yield);

                if (boost::algorithm::starts_with(data, "async"))
                {

                    //TODO: асинхронно педождать завершения операции в другом потоке


                    std::thread t([](){
                        //Долгая операция в другом потоке или io_service
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    });
                    t.detach();

                    boost::asio::async_write(s, boost::asio::buffer(data, n), yield);
                } else
                {
                    std::cout << "Received unknown command '" << std::string(data, data+n) << "'\n";
                }
            }
        });
    }

    iosvc.run();
}
```

Comment: Уточните, что подразумевается под словосочетанием _асинхронное ожидание_? Родительский поток должен остановится и подождать пока закончиться выполнение дочернего (в примере `std::thread t`) ?

Comment: @acade, сопрограмма должна приостановиться, в это время io_service занимается другими событиями(не блокируясь). А по завершению длительной операции в отдельном потоке должен быть какой-то механизм по возобновлению сопрограммы. Если писать без сопрограмм - мы бы вызывали iosvc.post() с полученным колбеком по завершению операции.

Comment: @acade, так же как мы в async_write передаем yield, и по завершению записи нас возобновляют. Вот я и хочу сделать такую функцию